# deleted record not removing from list knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Records (`comment`) are nested in foreach loop. When i delete record it deletes from database but does not remove from list. It removes from list when i refresh page.

my html code is :

```
<span data-bind="foreach:showAds">
    //some stuff
    <span data-bind="foreach:showComment">
        <span data-bind="attr:{'id':id}">
            <span data-bind="text:description"></span>
            <span data-bind="text:postedById"></span>
            <span data-bind="click:function(){ $parent.deleteComment($data.id)}">delete</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

js code is :

```
 function comment(data) {
        var self = this;
        data = data || {};
        self.description = ko.observable(data.description);
        self.postedById = data.postedById;
        self.adId = data.adId;
        self.id = data.id;
    }
    function ad(data) {
        var self = this;
        data = data || {};
        //some stuff
        self.showComment = ko.observableArray();
        if (data.comment) {
            var cmt = $.map(data.comment, function (item) { return new comment(item); });
            self.showComment(cmt);
        }
        self.deleteComment = function (id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Comment/DeleteComment/' + id,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    //Also how to map single object? $.map() is not working  for single object so I mapped it manually.
                    var com = new comment();
                    com.id = data.Id;
                    com.description = data.description;
                    com.adId = data.adId;
                    self.showComment.remove(com); //whats wrong here?
                },
                error: function () {
                    toastr.error("failed to delete comment", "Error!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.showAds = ko.observableArray();
        //load data using ajax and map in showAds.
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: A few comments on your code:
`var cmt = $.map(data.comment, function (item) { return new comment(item); });`
If you do a `new`, it's recommended to start the function name with upper case. So it'd be new Comment(data);

Also, if your BackEnd has the `id` property written with upper case I, in the function constructor you should use `data.Id` to define `self.id`. That way you could throw the BE result directly to the constructor.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this official documentation example

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: places">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removePlace">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function MyViewModel() {
         var self = this;
         self.places = ko.observableArray(['London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']);

         // The current item will be passed as the first parameter, so we know which place to remove
         self.removePlace = function(place) {
             self.places.remove(place)
         }
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

See that the first argument is the current element (so you could ask for the element id).

```
self.deleteComment = function (comment) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/Comment/DeleteComment/' + comment.id,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            self.showComment.remove(comment);
        }
    });
}
```

Remember now to use the click method without creating a new function

```
click: $parent.deleteComment
```

instead of

```
click: function(){ $parent.deleteComment($data.id)}
```

Comment: thanks! also how to map single object as mentioned in quesiton (commented code)

Comment: [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) needs an array and it's for doing a transformation on each element... I don't find it useful in your section.
What I would've done is to instantiate the comment using it's constructor.

`var com = new comment({
   id: data.Id,
   description: data.description,
   adId: data.adId
});`

But also remember that now with this new fix, there's no need to create a new instance of the comment you are about to delete, so you are good :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom remove() function. the normal remove is trying to match up an object that matches exactly, and you aren't populating all the fields. Since you already have the id, just use that:

```
    self.deleteComment = function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Comment/DeleteComment/' + id,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                self.showComment.remove(function(item){
                    return item.id == id;
                }); 
            },
            error: function () {
                toastr.error("failed to delete comment", "Error!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand custom remove function. please provide implementation of custom remove function.

Comment: I did. did you even look at my answer?

Comment: yeah its receiving item as parameter which confused me

Comment: item is the current item in the array that knockout passes to the inner function. similar to a $.each

Comment: can you put up a fiddle or anything testable?

Comment: @IrfanWattoo fixed it, there was a typo in the compare function (assignment vs equality check)

Comment: thanks!! It worked. how to map single object? (as I asked in question )

Comment: Use the knockout mapping plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: I want to map using jquery. As I mentioned in question I used `$.map()` to map multiple objects. But there is single object so `$.map` is not working. so I have mapped it manually(shown in question). Is there any function for this like `$.each`.